# Push Notification to android device with custom GCM parameters

Tags: javascript, quickblox

I am using JavaScript SDK - v2.1.2 :

My Query : How to send push notification with custom gcm parameters in android device using JavaScript.

I am trying to send push notification to android devices with my JavaScript code but in our app we are using third party receiver called **CleverTap** for notification.
Following are the mandatory parameters for CleverTap receiver: 
**"wzrk_pn"
"wzrk_sound"
"nt"
"nm"
"wzrk_dl"** which I need to send as custom parameters.

Following is my code for Push Notification :

```
var pushCustomParams = {
    message: 'Message received from Bob',
    wzrk_pn: 1,
    wzrk_sound: 1,
    nt: 'Revofit',
    nm: 'This msg is from application',
    wzrk_dl: ''
}
var params = {
    notification_type : 'push',
    push_type : 'gcm', // 'gcm' is for Android, 'apns' - for iOS.
    user : { ids: [14411551] }, // recipients.
    environment : 'development', // environment, can be 'production' as well.
    message :   QB.pushnotifications.base64Encode(JSON.stringify(pushCustomParams)), // See how to form iOS or Android spesific push notifications
};

 QB.pushnotifications.events.create(params, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // success
        console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

Logs generated after executing the above code is as follows:

```
 {
    "notification": {
        "registration_ids": ["dFCRdN7MJD0:APA91bFsaOdorqhvRyMuUGH-Ds8Z_EB6pQWHpQIYy5YVUefwYFwqK39E5BsLtJ2cHYDLv9mPXDQc4mAQRhJTdM2unUgy6-kmWSWMorp0ZSbBL1EdjFZLiorh4LQT3JR454dqEP1bL2_l"],
        "delay_while_idle": false,
        "data": {
             "message": "{\"message\":\"Message received from Bob\",\"wzrk_pn\":1,\"wzrk_sound\":1,\"nt\":\"Revofit\",\"nm\":\"This msg is from application\"}",
             "collapse_key": "event7637817"
    },
          "priority": "high",
         "time_to_live": 86400
     },
     "log": [{
        "device_token": null,
        "created_at": "2016-06-30T14:26:46Z",
        "delivered_at": "2016-06-30T14:26:47Z",
        "failed_at": null,
        "error_code": null,
       "error_description": null
     }]
    }
```

But when I tried to send push notification from admin panel with my customized channel setting of GCM Parameters it worked fine.
Log generated for notification from admin panel :

```
 {
     "notification": {
        "registration_ids":     ["eShiPWpBngA:APA91bFzFeaB0LryAt9FmEJ9xl2KHWhZWlfzpYhng4KONN60yr3ySl2R58Eye-qSmhzQ56T2Fyuzr0Yg4y1VWMIm20LH74U7BWO_Az7MgogBD2IGvmWEKvJWWgVH6sD-3wP_gaIgJEAY"],
        "delay_while_idle": false,
         "data": {
            "message": "hii",
            "wzrk_pn": "1",
            "nm": "New message",
            "nt": "revofit",
            "collapse_key": "event7632938"
         },
        "priority": "high",
        "time_to_live": 86400
     },
    "log": [{
        "device_token": null,
        "created_at": "2016-06-30T08:17:25Z",
         "delivered_at": "2016-06-30T08:17:26Z",
        "failed_at": null,
        "error_code": null,
        "error_description": null
    }]
 }
```

I am unable to rectify my mistake 
Kindly Help me out with this.

Sorry for my bad English. I tried my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we weren't able to get the solution as required we changed the GCM receiver.